# Hide HTML form unless certain querystring is selected

Tags: html, forms, query-string

```
<form name=dateform method="get">
    Select Date:
    <a href="http://www.test.com/test/default.asp?action=home" onclick="location.href=this.href+'&rundate='+rundate;return false;"></a>

    <script language="JavaScript" src="calendar_us.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css">
    <script language="JavaScript">
    new tcal ({
        // form name
        'formname': 'dateform',
        // input name
        'controlname': 'rundate'
    });
    </script>
    <font size="1"></font>
        <input type="text" name="rundate" size="20" value="<%response.write(rundate)%>">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1">
    </form>
```

And this is my case statement

```
<%SELECT CASE action%>
        <%CASE "HOME"%>
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
        <%CASE "CB"%>
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
        <%CASE "CM"%>
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
        <%CASE "L"%>
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
        <%CASE "ALL"%>
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->

        <%CASE "Z"%>
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
```

And I only want the form to show when home is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic ASP is spaghetti code, so this should work just fine:

```
<%SELECT CASE action%>
        <%CASE "HOME"%>
            <form name=dateform method="get">
            Select Date:
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <!--#include virtual="/test/stest.asp"-->
...
```

Can't see how this question is related to JavaScript.. ?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something like this that i found on google

<%
dim theDisplay
if request.querystring("theVariable") = "show" then
theDisplay = "block"
else
theDisplay = "none"
end if
%>

<div style="display:<%=theDisplay%>"></div>

but your way worked great